# Issue in using Langchain and Opensearch to query multiple indices at once - Python

Tags: python, openai-api, opensearch, langchain, amazon-opensearch

I have this `Opensearch` `Vector DB` and I maintain multiple `indices` that start with "index-" (for example `index-pdf`, `index-html`). I have indexed sets of documents to each of the indices using `Langchain's` `OpenSearchVectorSearch.from_documents()` function.

Now, I want to run some queries which I want them to be run across multiple `indices`. An example would be "What is the title of each document?". When I execute the below code, it either just outputs answer from the first or last matching `index`, or says it cannot find the answer. Here is my current code:

```
from langchain.vectorstores import OpenSearchVectorSearch
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA, ConversationalRetrievalChain
import os
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI


embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

def get_llm(model):
    llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name=model.lower(), verbose=False, temperature=0)
    return llm


docsearch = OpenSearchVectorSearch(opensearch_url="http://localhost:9200",
                                           
                                            index_name="index-*",
                                            embedding_function=embeddings)



chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm=get_llm("gpt-3.5-turbo"),
    retriever=docsearch.as_retriever(),
)


result = chain({'question': 'What is the title of each document?', "chat_history": []})
response = result['answer']

print(response)
```

How can I effectively run a `Langchain` based query on multiple indices (or all indices) and get a response back? Sample questions could be listing all document names/titles.

Comment: Have you tried using the `RetrievalQA` first before trying to chain them together? https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/how_to/vector_db_qa

Comment: The `OpenSearchVectorSearch` object looks like it's created fine. Docs show more info on how to match any custom field names up as well https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/opensearch#using-a-preexisting-opensearch-instance

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an OpenSearch [index alias](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/im-plugin/index-alias/) is what you're looking for. Using this OpenSearch feature, you can point to one or more indexes using a proxy identifier.

So rather than `index_name="index-*`, you'd simply reference your newly-created index alias name, e.g., `index_name="my-index`. LangChain will recognize this as a standard index reference, while OpenSearch will distribute queries to the indexes that comprise `my-index`.

Cheers!